# Sorting and storing content in Solr

Tags: sitecore

Is it possible for me to sort my content based on certain fields, and store the items in that order into Solr?
eg: All items that contain the word "Lorem" in the title should be sorted to the top, followed by items that contain "Ipsum" in the body field.
How would I do this?

Note: This should happen when I rebuild my index in Sitecore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Solr is an index, not a db/document store, you can't really "sort" the content. However, you can sort the output based on certain fields. Since you mention you want to do this index time, I guess you have some logic there where you can determine in what order you want the output to be. If so, you could add a numeric computed field containing a sort order value and then order by that value query time. This is mostly relevant when Solr is used for filtering a large amount of content.

If your case is more related to text search and you want to boost certain terms etc., I'd suggest you look into sorting the output by score and make sure you put your content into indexable fields in such way that you can boost relevant fields at query time.